# New Trees growing from old root system

Tags: fruit-trees

I have two little apple trees growing out of the main root system of a 30yr old Apple tree. Is it possible to relocate them to a different part of the yard?  They are roughly 4 feet and 6 feet away from the trunk. The old tree is too close to our cedars and full of disease and cankar. It was taller than our house when we moved in and over the years have cut back a few feet at a time to not stress out the tree.  We really like the apples and would like to graft from the old tree or replant these new ones growing from it.(as long as the disease doesn’t transfer with it too) [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that growth is coming off the roots, as it likely is, most apple trees are grafted onto different rootstocks,so even if you dug them up and grew them on elsewhere, they won't be the same as your apple tree, nor have the same fruit I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean cedar-apple rust, it can spread great distances like a mile. My guess is that the two small trees are seedlings, if so, they are unlikely to have the same fruit as your old tree. If you want to chance the rust, I would buy a new tree at a nursery;  I understand that there are now varieties that have some resistance to rust.